# How to solve 2d array problem to store addresses of 1's given in matrix A into matrix B in Java

Tags: java, oop

[Java Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ns1.jpg)

This problem was given in my OOP exam. In which a 2d array is given containing zeroes and ones. We have to solve it such that I store addresses of ones into output matrix that is smaller in size as compared to the problem matrix and there is quite weird pattern of storing ones into the resultant matrix.

Comment: Strange question, as the addresses do not match the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example provided in the question doesn't provide a valid result.

Here is the closest to the original, that I could get.

```java
void map_reduce() {
    int[][] Matrix_A = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
    String[][] Matrix_B = new String[6][2];
    int indexA = 0, indexB, count;
    for (int[] row : Matrix_A) {
        indexB = count = 0;
        for (int value : row) {
            if (value == 1)
                Matrix_B[indexA][count++] = "(%d, %d)".formatted(indexA, indexB);
            indexB++;
        }
        indexA++;
    }
}
```

```
[(0, 6), null]
[null, null]
[(2, 1), null]
[(3, 0), null]
[(4, 1), (4, 3)]
[null, null]
```